# AWS Cluster Mode Certificate Issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2

I am trying to setup a WSO2 Cluster using aws mode but I am receiving this error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target {com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoinerOverAWS}
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:67)

Do you know which certificate I need to add to the truststore?

Where can I get those certificates?

Any clue is very welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding this [certificate](https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&id=SO5624&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US)

Thanks,